# How do I add event to the ::after?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, events

So I got my script with the DOM:
[HTML and JS](https://codeshare.io/QnXy7e)
When I hoover cursor over one of the given blocks it changes text color in all of them.
Here's the CSS:
[CSS](https://codeshare.io/8pjEVE)
And I wanted to make it change color also on the background of the buttons.
But I don't know how to get "inside" this "h3::after".

```js
function kolor(color) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = color;
  document.getElementsByTagName('h3')[0].style.h3::after.bgColor = color;
}
```

```html
<h3 onmouseover="kolor('#c90000');">Red</h3>
<h3 onmouseover="kolor('#008BCC');">Blue</h3>
<h3 onmouseover="kolor('#fedf00');">Yellow</h3>
```

Comment: Please don't post links to your code. Post the relevant code right here in your question.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know how to format it properly to post it there

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example That should help you put code direct into your question.

Comment: Before and after pseudo elements aren’t actually in the DOM so you can’t format them in JS the way you have been trying. Look into setting a CSS variable.

Comment: Also see: [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)